# Using jQuery to show an alert based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to display an alert based on the radio button selected by the user. So if the user selects, for example, radiobutton1 then a message for that particular radio button will appear.

This is the form I have so far;

```
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="campus" value="Campus 1"> Campus 1 </br>
        <input type="radio" name="campus" value="Campus 2"> Campus 2 </br>
        <input type="radio" name="campus" value="Campus 3"> Campus 3 </br>
        <input type="radio" name="campus" value="Campus 4"> Campus 4 </br>
    </form>
    <input type='button' value='Display Selected' id='click'>
```

I know how to make an alert that shows the radio button value but unable to display a particular message based on the selection. Advanced thanks for any assistance!

Comment: What kind of message do you want to display? Where will it be stored?

Comment: Please post the jQuery code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RXcYy/9/

```
$(function(){
   $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
     alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
 $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(function () {
      $("#click").click( function(){
        alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());

        // Or alert($('input[name=campus]:radio:checked').val()); to be more specific
      });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rh2jt/)**</kbd>